# Isabelle class obligation prove blue

Tags: isabelle

in Isabelle I have the following file

```
theory Scratch
imports Main 
begin

class named =
  fixes getName :: "'a ⇒ string"

class node = named

datatype Node = node string

fun getName_Node :: "Node ⇒ string" where
  "getName_Node (node str) = str"

instantiation Node :: node
begin
instance proof
qed
end
end
```

the part 'instance' is underlined with a blue line. When I hover the curses over the info provided:

```
Auto solve_direct: The current goal can be solved directly with
  Scratch.class.Scratch.node.of_class.intro: OFCLASS(?'a, node_class)
```

What can I do to prevent 'instance' to be underlined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a hint by the system and can be safely ignored. Usually it's helpful to see that the proposition you're about to prove already exists somewhere.

Nonetheless, to disable, go to jEdit's "Plugins" menu, and choose "Plugin Options". There, go to the "Isabelle / General" item in the tree. You'll see a bunch of options. In the section "Automatically tried tools", disable "Auto Solve Direct".